# Blank App (XAML) Equivalent in Visual Studio Community 2015

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2015

I'm working through the Head First C# (3rd ed) text with instructions specific to VS 2012 and I'm having trouble finding the equivalent in VS Community 2015.

The text says to begin a new project with Windows Store -> Blank App (XAML) but I don't see that as an option in my version of VS. The closest I could find was Windows Forms Application but that doesn't seem to be right since it didn't generate the MainPage.xaml among other things.

Comment: From the forum: _VS2015 doesn't call them "Windows Store" apps any more. Instead, just look for "Windows 8.1" and Visual C# when you're creating projects. The book asks you to create Blank App projects. To do this, create a new project, and in the New Project window use the "Search for installed templates (Ctrl-E)" box in the upper right-hand corner to search for 'blank', then choose "Blank App (Windows 8.1)    Visual C#". After that, it should show up as one of the items in the New Projects window._

Answer (score 4):

WPF is the closest you can get if you're not on Windows 8, the book says it too and it links to [here](http://cdn.oreilly.com/oreilly/pdfs/hfcsharp3e_WPF_download.pdf) where you can get the WPF version of the chapters.

Comment: I'm on Windows 8 and using a more recent version of VS than what is required for the text so I didn't think that the technology would go backwards.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, a Windows Forms Application will be very different.  While it may  not be identical, the:

New Project ->  Visual C# -> Windows -> Windows 8 -> Windows -> Blank App (Windows 8.1) is probably the closest.

Comment: Under Windows I only see Classic Desktop and no option for "Windows 8." Am I missing a package?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  But I'm using 2019 version.

The answer seems to be to install the Universal Windows Platform development package from the Visual Studio installer (Modify button).

Then you can search for the correct project type by first selecting C# as the language and then typing 'blank app' and selecting the Blank App (Universal Windows) option.