# Sample code issue xamarin forms quick start

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am new to mobile development. For this i am practicing on xamarin forms and following this [sample code](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/). But there are some issues in it which i couldn't understand.

First is that there is no `Mainpage.xaml` file in the solution, i have to add it manually like bellow image

[image]

Further more in sample code they said to copy paste `app.xaml.cs` code into my solution file with same name. But there is no such file named like this as also shown in the above image. But i do have `app.cs` file so i copy pasted that code into this file and i get the following error

Moreover when i run it i get a following message

I have searched many articles on this but couldn't find the right answer

Any help would be highly appreciated

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you got everything right? When I download the code it runs straight away without having to add anything.

Comment: @GeraldVersluis yes i have done everything according to the sample in the link

Answer (score 1):

## Template

Looking at the [quickstart](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/hello-xamarin-forms/quickstart/) it references the Blank **Xaml** App(Xamarin.Forms Portable) template. When checking my own Visual Studio 2015(Windows 10) this template doesn't exist and creating a Blank App(Xamarin.Forms Portable leaves me in a similar situation to your own; no Mainpage.xaml.

## App.xaml.cs

In a forms project the app.cs class is used to initialize your layout. This is not the same as a App.xaml.cs; App.xaml.cs would be a backing file for an associated App.xaml file. You could try looking at this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31600734/blank-app-xaml-equivalent-in-visual-studio-community-2015) to see if that template will layout what you need. Although, looking again at the quickstart it seems like it's no longer in line with the [sample project](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/Phoneword/Phoneword/Phoneword/App.cs). Instead of replacing all of the code in App.cs, it should be fine to replace

```
 MainPage = new ContentPage
  {
    Content = new StackLayout
    {
      VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
      Children = {
        new Label {
          XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
          Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
        }
      }
    }
  };
```

with

```
MainPage = new MainPage();
```

This should be enough to tell the app that you want your default page to be the MainPage they had you make earlier. Hope this helps.